# Não rodar vídeo autoplay como bg em mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, vídeo

Meu site tem como `bg` um vídeo que está em `autoplay`.

Porém, quando está em mobile, quero que este vídeo não rode, deixando apenas em `pause` para aparecer uma imagem de fundo.

Se eu coloco `display:none` no CSS ele fica um `bg` preto.

```
<video nocontrols muted autoplay loop>
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <object data="video1.mp4"></object>
</video>
```

e no CSS mobile:

```
video{ display:none }
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: <video nocontrols muted autoplay loop>
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <object data="video1.mp4"></object>
 </video>

e no CSS mobile: video{
display:none
}

Levando em conta que cada pagina do site é um video diferente do outro.

Comment: Você pode tirar o autoplay fixo da tag. E ao iniciar a tela, por javascript controlar se deve ou não dar autoplay no vídeo.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS [Media types](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp)  para fazer a diferença entre mobile e desktop.
remova a diretiva loop da tag e utilize Javascript (jQuery para facilitar) para colocar o atributo quando necessário.

Exemplos:

[Html5 video loop e Jquery](http://www.joncaveman.com/old/?p=19)